# Workspace switching breaks xpra switching

Tags: xubuntu, workspaces, mint

I have two machines, A and B. **A runs mint, B runs xubuntu**. I use xpra to use programs running on B through A (A is client B is server). When I hit `ctrl-alt-arrow-key` to switch workspaces, the windows close, xpra crashes, and I get the following error:

`ValueError: cannot encode '[45, 1, 0, 100, {'refresh-now': False, 'batch': {'reset': True}}, {'workspace': None}]'
2017-11-02 13:26:03,807 Connection lost`

(This is from the tail end of the error - I'm omitting a big long traceback that's probably not useful.)

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed a very long time ago but the packages provided by the Ubuntu repositories are [fundamentally broken](https://www.xpra.org/trac/wiki/Packaging/DistributionPackages) and full of holes such as this one.

Comment: That sucks. For posterity: You can get the latest version here: https://www.xpra.org/trac/wiki/Download#Linux